# Unable to detect proxy on new server

Tags: nginx, proxy, detection

I use the following code to detect if users are behind proxy/vpn:

```
function checkUser()
{
    $proxy = null;
    $check = null;
    $proxy = ($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'] != 'gzip, deflate') ? true : false;
    if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION']) != 'keep-alive' || $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] != 'max-age=0')
    {
        $check = ($proxy === true) ? 'proxy' : 'vpn';
    }
    return $check;
}
$connection = checkUser();
switch($connection)
{
    case 'proxy': $var = 'It seems you are behind Proxy.'; break;
    case 'vpn': $var = 'It seems you are using VPN.'; break;
    default: $var = 'No Proxy or VPN detected.'; break;
}
echo $var;
```

However it does work just fine on an older server I have, but on the new one it just doesn't. The new server is using Reverse Proxy Server (nginx). Can someone tell me if it has something to do with nginx and what I should adjust at the config. Thanks!

**--- EDIT: ---**

```
#user  nginx;
worker_processes  4;
worker_rlimit_nofile 950000;


#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

#pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  45000;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  5;
    #tcp_nodelay        on;

    #gzip  on;
    #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

        fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}
```

Comment: Your code is just wrong. HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING and HTTP_CONNECTION have nothing to do with proxies or VPN.

Comment: I got this code from this website: http://epichackers.net/Thread-PHP-Proxy-VPN-Detection. Tried different types of script to detect anonymous proxy. But all other script just always return proxy. So my question was: Has it something to do with nginx?

Comment: So, you have copied code without understanding what it does? It cannot work properly by design, though it can sometimes return right results. But random number generator can do the same as well.

Comment: I am just trying to understand what it is doing, and if it has something to do with nginx. Because all codes are returning proxy even when I am not using proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be based on the assumption that a proxy would disable the use of gzip/deflate and/or keep-alive sessions.  This is not an accurate assumption.  It is easier to implement a proxy if these features are turned off, but per the [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/draft-ietf-http-v11-spec-01.html) there is nothing that precludes a proxy working correctly with these features on.

So yes, nginx is probably just a better proxy and so the assumptions made by the author of that code above are now wrong.

The right way to check for an HTTP proxy is to look for the presence of an X-Forwarded-For header.  Something like this would suffice:

```
function isProxied() {
    $headers = array_change_key_case(apache_request_headers());
    return isset($headers["x-forwarded-for"]);
}
```

Technically, a proxy can be implemented without advertising it's presense (without adding an X-Forwarded-For header) - and some have an option to do this, in which case you're not really going to be able to detect this.  But most propxies will cooperate with you.

Note that if you are using a proxy in your own server stack (i.e. if you are running Varnish, Nginx or something else in front of Apache) then that could also adding an X-Forwarded-For header, so everything would appear to be proxied (based on [this,](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRealipModule) it looks like nginx uses "X-Real-IP" by default, so you likely don't need to worry about this).  If this is the case, either turn off the that option in Varnish/Nginx/whatever, or parse the X-Forwarded-For header to see if there are two IPs there instead of one.

Regarding VPN connections, I do not think you are going to find a reliable way to detect if the user is on VPN just from an incoming HTTP connection.  Although you might consider checking his origin IP to see if he is coming from a known TOR address or something of the sort.  Depending on how much you care about that.

Comment: I checked nginx/nginx.conf and couldn't find any line like given at the link you gave me. Correct me if I am searching in the wrong file or direction. I also do not know how to check if the "--with-http_realip_module" is currently active. And don't know how to set it to active. Do I need to reinstall nginx to do this?
I added my nginx.conf to my question, maybe you also have some commentary about that file/suggestions. Nginx and server configuration is all new for me and it's quite interesting me. And I am glad someone is helping me with this. Thanks again.

Comment: Pls see second to last para above.  I doubt you need to worry about that, since it appears nginx doesn't change the X-Forwarded-For header.  If all you want is a "is this proxied" function, go ahead and try the one above.  If it doesn't work, do a print_r($headers); and see what headers you do get and go from there.

Comment: When I debug headers, I get both x-forward-for and x-real-ip containing both same IP's and only one IP for x-forward-for. With and without using proxy

Comment: My guess is that whatever proxy you are using isn't adding the x-forwaded-for header (and nginx is), in which case you will not be able to detect it.

Comment: So I will not able to detect if a user is using proxy because of nginx?

Comment: Not to be mean, but you will not be able to detect a proxy because you don't understand what is happening and are asking me instead of looking for yourself.  My suggestion would be to - if possible, use something like Wireshark to sniff the traffic you are sending to the proxy (from your browser), and then again what is coming back from the proxy to your server (or nginx in this case it looks like).  Compare the two and see if a header is being added, then detect the presence of that header.  If you cannot perform that task yourself, then you're not really going to be able to solve the problem